# manage.py createsuperuser is not working with custom user model

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django, and I've created a custom user model to be able to use E-mail as main login method instead of username..  everything worked but I can't create a superuser using the command `python manage.py createsuperuser`.

Here are my codes :

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.db.models import CASCADE
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from .managers import UserManager

    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
        user_name = models.CharField(_('user name'), max_length=35)
        email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff'), default=False)
        is_superuser = models.BooleanField(_('superuser'), default=False)
        avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', null=True, blank=True)

        objects = UserManager()


        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = []


        class Meta:
            verbose_name = _('user')
            verbose_name_plural = _('users')

        def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
            '''
            Sends an email to this User.
            '''
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

And here are **managers.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

    class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
        use_in_migrations = True

        def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
            """
            Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
            """
            if not email:
                raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
            user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save(using=self._db)
            return user

        def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
            extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
            return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

        def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
            extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

            if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
                raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

            return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

The process creates a normal user not superuser , and it is created.
but I can't log in to admin panel `/admin`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't log in super users created on the django admin backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51117217/cant-log-in-super-users-created-on-the-django-admin-backend)

Comment: At top of post you are saying "I can't create a superuser" and at end "The process of creating superuser works great" ? I am confused what is the problem ? could you please explain.

Comment: @PankajSharma edited `The process creates a normal user not superuser `

Comment: If you are getting any error while creating superuser ?

Comment: no, no errors at all

Comment: did you set your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in setting.py file ?

Comment: yes `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'web_site.User'`  .. creating normal users from the website itself using the created forms are working fine, only superuser and admin panel that I can't access

Comment: I think you haven't set `is_staff = True` is making problem, I have posted a answer give a try to it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can implement the UserManager like following. it's simpler than your code.

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None):

        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('Users must have an email address.')

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email))
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):

        if password is None:
            raise TypeError('Superusers must have a password.')

        user = self.create_user(email, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()

        return user
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this field to User model

```
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and in UserManager set `is_admin = True`:

```
    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            username=username,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

For your SuperUser, make sure that `is_staff` is `true`, so add these line to your `User` model

```
@property
def is_staff(self):
    return self.is_admin
```

Try out this and tell if it works

Comment: Why not set the `is_staff` field directly?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too.  When doing createsuperuser operation, I got this:

```
site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 187, in check_key
return self.graph.root_nodes(key[0])[0]
```

I finally found my fix which is different from those listed here.
My fix was: I needed to do a django migration of my custom user model. Then it works!