# createsuperuser is not working with custom user model

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I know this question is a repeat (I've looked at similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462947/manage-py-createsuperuser-is-not-working-with-custom-user-model) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65161186/django-custom-superuser-cant-create-new-user-in-admin-panel) although the I still couldn't anywhere with the solutions. I've created a custom user model for my application but when I create a superuser I can't seem to sign in on the admin panel. What have I done wrong?

user model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must provide an email to create an account')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must provide a username to create an account')
        
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            password=password
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user



class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser):
    email               = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    username            = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined         = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login          = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last_login', auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin            = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active           = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser        = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD      = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS     = ['username']

    objects = UserAccountManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return f'email: {self.email}\nusername: {self.username}'


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def  has_module_perm(self, app_label):
        return True
```

my settings

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-l9=z0v(f%w$s9wx2)8$bgz&kfd##ap6rk&ug%hu^q3ju*04q%+'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# set custom user model
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.UserAccount'


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # additions
    'rest_framework',
    'account'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'type_tag.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'type_tag.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Comment: what is the extra functionality needed that you are creating a custom User model ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what I want to add right now. I just wanted to leave the model open for extension.

Comment: if you just wabt to add extra fielkds to users models, there is an integrated approach, an easier m,method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `create_superuser` does not have `user.is_active = True` and you `is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)` is also missing from your model, and you need to have `PermissionsMixin` if you are using `AbstractBaseUser`

Below is your working model and UserAccountManager, check it:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin

class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must provide an email to create an account')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must provide a username to create an account')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):

        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            password=password
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last_login', auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'email: {self.email}\nusername: {self.username}'

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perm(self, app_label):
        return True
```